# Джоин с таблицей если условие истинно

Tags: sql, oracle

желаемая логика (псевдокод) :

```
IF #var# is null THEN
select * from C
ELSE
select * from C c join A a ON c.object_id = a.id AND a.name = #var#
```

Пусть есть некоторый парсер sql, который вставит вместо #var# некоторое значение(пусть даже и null).
Имеется таблица A , у которой колонки : id INT, name VARCHAR.
А так же таблица C, с колонками : object_id INT, далее поля не важны.
object_id - первичный ключ, id - внешний ключ к object_id.
/#var# - это значение колонки name. Если /#var# равен null, то надо просто вывести все значения из C, иначе, через джоин найти подходящие варианты.
Задача сводится к тому, что бы *отключить* джоин, если параметр нулевой.
Без pl\sql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробую раскрыть поподробнее ответ пользователя **Saidolim**.

Попробуем выполнить предложенный им вариант и посмотреть, что получается:

```
create table c (id int, object_id int);
create table a (id int, name varchar2(10))
/
explain plan for
select * 
from c 
  left join a on c.object_id = a.id and a.name = :var AND :var is not null
/
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display)
/
```

В результате у нас получится такой план запроса:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation            | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |      |     1 |    26 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS OUTER  |      |     1 |    26 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL  | C    |     1 |    26 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |   VIEW               |      |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |    FILTER            |      |       |       |            |          |
|*  5 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL| A    |     1 |    20 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   4 - filter(:VAR IS NOT NULL)
   5 - filter("C"."OBJECT_ID"="A"."ID" AND "A"."NAME"=:VAR)
```

Самое главное для нас тут это 4 пункт плана. Там находится фильтр который проверяет, что `var` не равен `null`. Если результат проверки будет отрицательным, то та часть плана которая идет после фильтра (в нашем случае это обращение к таблице `A`) выполнятся не будет, что и требуется.

Answer (score 2):

попробуйте так

```
select * 
  from C c 
  left join A a ON c.object_id = a.id AND a.name = #var# AND #var# IS NOT NULL
```

Если `#var# = NULL` правые поля будут пустыми

Comment: в случае равенства параметра нулю, будет полный обход С и А , таблица А слишком большая для этого. Проблема как раз втом, что бы отключить этот обход!

Comment: @voipp Oracle умеет переписывать запрос и не выполнять соединение если понимает, что от него не изменится результирующим набор.  Попробую, если получится, попозже расписать это.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно использовать UNION.

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM   c 
WHERE  :var IS NULL
UNION  ALL
SELECT c.*
FROM   c, a
WHERE  :var IS NOT NULL 
AND    c.object_id = a.id 
AND    a.name = :var
```

Или EXISTS.

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM   c
WHERE  :var IS NULL 
OR     EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM a WHERE c.object_id = a.id AND a.name = :var)
```